# Qt - How to get the "Temp" dir for an arbitrary user?

Tags: c++, qt, temporary-files, dir

For each OS there is a location for storing temporary data. It could be like: C:/Users/[user name]/AppData/Temp (or so). How can I get this path independently from OS with QT?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is not possible to get the temp directory for an arbitrary user, but for the current user you can use [`QDir::temp()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdir.html#temp) or [`QDir::tempPath()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qdir.html#tempPath).

Comment: Good point about the arbitrary != current user. The directory for an arbitrary user may in fact be created on demand (common in corporate Win32 environments)

Comment: @Job The post is a bit old, is there a way to get user's tmp dir? If the system-wide is used, when several users are logged in that causes a collision.

Answer (score 4):

You want to get `QDesktopServices::TempLocation`. See http://doc.trolltech.com/qtextended4.4/qdesktopservices.html#StandardLocation-enum for details.

Comment: **Please note** what the [current Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices-obsolete.html) say: "The following members of class QDesktopServices are obsolete. They are provided to keep old source code working. We strongly advise against using them in new code." - seems like this member of the class is deprecated...

Comment: The links seems to be down and I can not find this in the official docs (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html). Could you please update the link?

Answer (score 2):

In Qt 5, you can use `QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::TempLocation)` to get the temporary directory path as a QString. You'll need to `#include <QStandardPaths>` to do so.